# Gulp copy folder structure, but only symlink the files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a project with a certain folder structure and an other project which should be basically the same only some files are different.

I would like to write a `gulp-task` (or tasks) which are copying the first projects folder structure, but only create `symlinks` for the files, and **don't overwrite** files already in the other project.

I found out that I can create `symlinks` with `gulp` and `vinyl-fs`.

I tried to create a two step task. First, I tried to copy the folder structure, but I don't know how can I tell gulp that **I only care about the folder structure**.

Then second, I wanted to create a `symlink` task that is creating the `symlinks` in the correct directory.

Maybe, I could create it with only `vinyl-fs`'s symlinks using a function parameter, but I can't find out how.

Comment: Yup, but I still got copied all the files under the folder, and recursively. To be precise I tried this:
`gulp.src('base/**').pipe(gulp.dest('target/'))`

Comment: For symlinking, I found out that I can use a function parameter and return the folder where I want to create the symlink for the given file.

like this: `vfs.src('base/**', { nodir: true }).pipe(vfs.symlink((file) => { return `target/${file.relative}`;});`

The problem with this is that the relative is giving back the path with the filename (as it should) but I onl need the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem you can do this to copy only folders (exclude `*.*`):

```
gulp
    .src(['base/path/**/*', '!base/path/**/*.*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('target'));
```

Assuming all your files have some kind of extension (e.g. `*.jpg`).

For the `symlinks`, doesn't the following work?:

```
var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');

...
vfs
    .src('base/path/**/*', { followSymlinks: false, nodir: true })
    .pipe(vfs.symlink('target'));
...
```

Comment: For the folder structure it works fine. Now, I have to fiure out how to symlink the files into the correct folder.

Comment: Oh, I should have tought about that before! Yeah, that works just fine!
I don't even need two steps. Symlinking will create the folders for the links as well. I mark this as an answer.